# Hall-Littlewood polynomials with sage

Tags: reference-request, computer-algebra, symmetric-functions, symmetric-polynomials, sage

I need to make some computations with Sage involving Hall-Littlewood polynomials. I couldn't find any satisfying information in the Sage manuals/tutorials that I found on the internet. What I found is rather poor.
Could anyone give me a good reference ?

Comment: What is wrong with https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/combinat/sage/combinat/sf/hall_littlewood.html ?

Comment: @mathoverflowUser Since I'm not an expert in symmetric polynomials, I find this reference a bit too technical.

Comment: You can post Sage-specific questions to ask.sagemath.org and/or to the Google group sage-support. Perhaps describe what you want to compute and ask at those sites?

Comment: @PaulBroussous: It would help if you can describe in mathematical / latex terms here or as JohnPalmieri suggested to sage-support what it is that you want to compute.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice!